# Writing to conf.js file during execution

Tags: angularjs, protractor

**The Goal:** I have to write a test that changes a user's password, without breaking old tests.

**The Problem:**
In our system, all previous passwords are **forbidden** to be used again. As a result, once the test is complete I cannot go back and revert the change to the old password.

**My Current Idea:** The password is stored in params in my conf.js file, so my thought is to somehow overwrite the line in that file with the new password so that all previously written tests still work. Is this possible?

All thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: if u have password in param in config file then you should be able to pass this from CLI as well. check this command it will give u an idea protractor conf.js --parameters.password

Comment: Acid it is a nice idea that I also came across here: [link](http://moduscreate.com/protractor_parameters_adding_flexibility_automation_tests/) The issue is that this still means that the user must manually keep a record of the updated password and pass that into the command line